# Change selected option Jquery

Tags: jquery

I use this to add options in my select list :

```
$("#row_list").append(new Option(item.row_id, item.row_id));
```

I would like to change the selected option with this code :

```
row_value = tab.cols[i].row_id;
$('#row_list option[value=row_value]').prop('selected', true);
```

But it doesn't work.
I tried the same code without using append and it works.

Have you an idea ?

Thanks.

**Complete code :**

```
var rows = {};
var cols = {};

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.get('../get_rows/', function(rows_data) {
        rows = rows_data;
        addRowOpt(1);
    }, null, 'json');
    $.get( '../get_cols/', function( cols_data ) {
        cols = cols_data;
        addColOpt(1);
    }, null, 'json');
});

function addRowOpt(populate) {
    populate = populate || 0;
    try {
        rowsTab = JSON.parse(rows);

        $('#row_list').find('option').remove().end();
        $('#id_row_del').find('option').remove().end();

        $.each(rowsTab['rows'], function (i, item) {
            $("#row_list").append(new Option(item.row_id, item.row_id));
            $('#id_row_del').append(new Option(item.row_id, item.row_id));

            if(populate) {
                $("#container_corps").append('<div id="' + item.row_id + '" class="row"></div>');
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}

$('#edit_col').click(function() {
    var id_edit = $('#id_col_del').val();
    var tab = JSON.parse(cols);
    for(var i = tab.cols.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        if (tab.cols[i].col_id === id_edit) {
            row_value = tab.cols[i].row_id;
            $('#row_list option[value=' + row_value + ']').prop('selected', true);

            addRowOpt();
        }
    }
});
```

And my list :

```
<body>
    <div id="top">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="config">
            <div class="col-sm-16">
                <p>
                    ...
                    Add to row <select name="row_list" id="row_list">
                    </select>
                    <input type="button" id="add_col" value="Add col" /><br /><br />
                </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

hmm can you do

```
$("#row_list").val(row_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate string properly with `+` operator:

```
var row_value = tab.cols[i].row_id;
$('#row_list option[value=' + row_value + ']').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work (i also tried to set directcly the value : option[value="val1"]). Maybe a problem with DOM ?